# Having trouble creating a play framework web app in IntelliJ with scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

When I try and create a play project in intelliJ with a java SDK (Using scala) I get the following error after the project is created:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1524)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$40.apply(Defaults.scala:1040)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$40.apply(Defaults.scala:1040)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:177)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:67)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:76)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 21: file:////C:/Users/Ras Brits/.activator/repository
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
```

The project also has no packages so I think there might be something wrong with the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file "C:/Users/Ras Brits/.activator/repository", replace all "file://" with "file:///".